# Is an emergency account the same as rescue mode?

Tags: rescue-mode

I found a question in the **Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_STIG 1.5.2** that reads,

> The Ubuntu operating system must automatically remove or disable emergency accounts after 72 hours...

What is an emergency account? Is it different from booting in rescue mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the Description field of the same rule (Finding V-238331, Rule SV-238331r654168_rule):

> Description
> Emergency accounts are different from infrequently used accounts (i.e., local logon accounts used by the organization's System Administrator s when network or normal logon/access is not available). Infrequently used accounts are not subject to automatic termination dates Emergency accounts are accounts created in response to crisis situations, usually for use by maintenance personnel. [...]

They are completely different.